# Error while accessing the django admin page as follows - TypeError at /admin/login/ _getfullpathname: illegal type for path parameter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, django-settings

While working upon the project, an error as mentioned above creeps in and I'm no longer able to access the Django admin page and haven't yet been able to find a way around it. All help will be appreciated.

The admin.py in the apps directory -

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Page , Category , UserProfile

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Page)
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

The settings.py -

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '&=k(67-(72)h_w%f3b#4&fuop1+-_uyv3$lwx5(qz1*1il0^2x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tango_with_django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tango_with_django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'media')
]
```

The urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls'))
]
```

The urls.py within the app -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns , url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$' , views.index , name = 'index' ) ,
    url(r'^about/' , views.about , name = 'about' ) ,
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$' , views.category , name = 'category'),
    url(r'^add_category/', views.add_category, name = 'add_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name>\w+)/add_page/$' , views.add_page , name = 'add_page'),
    url(r'^register/$' , views.register , name = 'register'),
]
```

The Traceback error as follows -

```
Template error:
In template C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\login.html, error at line 0
   _getfullpathname: illegal type for path parameter   1 : {% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
   2 : {% load i18n admin_static %}
   3 : 
   4 : {% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/login.css" %}" />
   5 : {{ form.media }}
   6 : {% endblock %}
   7 : 
   8 : {% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} login{% endblock %}
   9 : 
   10 : {% block usertools %}{% endblock %}


Traceback:

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  172.                     response = response.render()

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  137.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py" in render
  201.         output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_static.py" in static
  17.     return _static(path)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\templatetags\staticfiles.py" in static
  9.     return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  204.             self._setup()

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py" in _setup
  394.         self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py" in __init__
  39.                                                  *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in __init__
  185.         self.location = abspathu(self.base_location)

File "C:\Python35-32\lib\ntpath.py" in abspath
  535.                 path = _getfullpathname(path)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: _getfullpathname: illegal type for path parameter
```

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT` in settings.py should be string, not list https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#media-root

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with your MEDIA_ROOT:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'media')
]
```

MEDIA_ROOT is different with STATICFILES_DIRS which is an list or tuple that can include more than one directory.

Try to modify MEDIA_ROOT as follow:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'media')
```

or

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../media/').replace('\\','/')
```